# Exact visual matches between common columns in dataframes not matching on merge

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge two dataframes on a common column, "long_name". But the merge is not happening for some names, even what look like visually exact matches, (ie "Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccittini" (df1) to "Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccittini" (df2)) when I merge on "long_name":

```
df_merged = df.merge(df1, on="long_name", indicator=True, how='right')
```

Lionel Messi is left out and according to the indicator column, he's a "right_only" row from the merge. What's odd is that "Neymar da Silva Santos Júnior" IS merging. Why is there a discrepancy between the rows? Both have been sourced consistently, df from kaggle and df2 from **scraping** and using the same script for all row name extractions.

I tried to isolate both the Lionel Messi entries from df and df1 using the following code:

```
name1 = df.loc[df.short_name == 'L. Messi', ["long_name"]]

name2 = df1.loc[df1.name == 'Lionel Messi', ["long_name"]]

name1.values == name2.values
```

But the result is `array([[False]])`. I'm not sure why they're not matching.

The first df looks like this (first 8 lines, `df = df.loc[0:7,["short_name", "long_name"]]`):

```
          short_name                            long_name
0           L. Messi       Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccittini
1  Cristiano Ronaldo  Cristiano Ronaldo dos Santos Aveiro
2          Neymar Jr        Neymar da Silva Santos Junior
3           J. Oblak                            Jan Oblak
4          E. Hazard                          Eden Hazard
5       K. De Bruyne                      Kevin De Bruyne
6      M. ter Stegen                Marc-André ter Stegen
7        V. van Dijk                      Virgil van Dijk
```

The second df looks like this (first 8 lines, `df1 = df1.loc[0:7,["name", "long_name"]]`):

```
                name                      long_name
0      Kylian Mbappé     Kylian Sanmi Mbappé Lottin
1             Neymar  Neymar da Silva Santos Júnior
2      Mohamed Salah                      محمد صلاح
3         Harry Kane              Harry Edward Kane
4        Eden Hazard            Eden Michael Hazard
5       Lionel Messi  Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccitini
6    Raheem Sterling      Raheem Shaquille Sterling
7  Antoine Griezmann              Antoine Griezmann
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Glancing at the 3 code examples you gave for isolating “Lionel Messi”, have you tried the first two without the square brackets around the column name in the `.loc[]`? Also, I really recommend using `[ ]` to access columns, instead of the dot/`.`/attribute method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is not just a case of a misspelled name?

`df` lists the `long_name` as `Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccittini`, whereas `df1` lists it as `Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccitini`. I notice `df` has 2 `t`'s in `Cuccittini` but `df` has 1.

Manually correct the second dataframe and retry.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I'll see if this is the cause of the behavior throughout the data set.